# Chevalley groups $G_{\mathbb{F}_2}$ in $G_\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: gr.group-theory, chevalley-groups

Is every (adjoint) Chevalley group over the field with two elements $G_{\mathbb{F}_2}$ isomorphic to a subgroup of its counterpart over the rationals $G_\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: I'm suspecting you mean specifically with structure coefficients just 0 or 1, or something similar?

Comment: Note that Will's proof even shows it doesn't, in general, embed into $G_\mathbf{C}$.

Comment: @‍WillSawin's [proof](https://mathoverflow.net/a/403082) [mentioned](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/403081/chevalley-groups-g-mathbbf-2-in-g-mathbbq#comment1032088_403081) by @YCor.

Comment: The smallest non-trivial representation of $E_8(2)$ has dimension at least $402653184$.

Answer (score 15):

$\DeclareMathOperator\GL{GL}\DeclareMathOperator\PGL{PGL}$No.

Here's a cheap argument. Let $G = \PGL_n $ for $n>8$ even. Inside $G_{\mathbb F_2}$, we have the group of upper-triangular matrices which differ from the identity matrix only in the upper-right quadrant of the matrix. This group is isomorphic to $(\mathbb Z/2)^{n^2/4}$.

It suffices to prove that $(\mathbb Z/2)^{n^2/4}$ does not embed into $\PGL_n$ in characteristic $0$.

Let's first lift from $\PGL_n$ to $\GL_n$. The commutator map from $(\mathbb Z/2)^{n^2/4} \times (\mathbb Z/2)^{n^2/4}$ to the $n$th roots of unity clearly lies in the $2$nd root of unity, and is symplectic, so it must have an isotropic subspace of dimension $n^2/8$. The inverse image of that group is abelian, thus also contains a subgroup isomorphic to $(\mathbb Z/2)^{n^2/8}$.

But any finite abelian subgroup of $\GL_n$ may be simultaneously diagonalized, so $(\mathbb Z/2)^m$ only embeds in $\GL_n$ if $m \leq n$. Since $n>8$ we have $n^2/8 > n$ and this is impossible.